# C# XNA Box2d: ApplyImpulse() acts surprisingly

Tags: c#, xna, physics, box2d

I'm trying to move a body:

```
if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up)) {
    rocket.ApplyImpulse(new Box2DX.Common.Vec2(0, 30f), rocket.GetPosition());
}
```

Oddly, the body only moves when the key is **released**. Why is this? I've been looking at the [manual](http://www.box2d.org/manual.html#d0e575) but can't figure it out.

When I remove the conditional, and just have the `applyImpulse()` call in `Step()`, the rocket continually has the animation of thrusters but never actually moves. (As if I had been holding down the Up key the entire time.)

Looks like what I really need to get this working is a better understanding of what the first argument to `applyImpulse()` does:

```
new Box2DX.Common.Vec2(0, 30f)
```

What is the significance of the two values in the vector?

**UPDATE** This works much better:

```
rocket.ApplyImpulse(new Box2DX.Common.Vec2(0, -1), rocket.GetPosition());
```

It looks like if the second value in the force vector is negative, the object rises on the screen. Before, the impulse applied was just slamming it into the floor. When I released the key, it would sometimes bounce back, if the impulse had been strong enough.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your update:  In XNA, depending on how you've situated your camera, negative Y is up.  If you want the rocket to go up, you have to apply a force in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

That makes no sense as to why it only moves when it's released, is there nothing else interfering with it elsewhere such as another keyboard input hidden somewhere? I only ask as it could be that another keyboard input statement in conflicting with another and causing the problem.